# Error when creating W7 iso from disk - "access denied"

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, iso-image

I need to create a W7 VM on Virtual Box. Virtual Box requires an .iso image of the OS to be installed.

To create the .ios image, ive loaded a W7 install CD i have into a USB CD enclosure (as i dont have any computers with a build in disk drive anymore) and attempted to make a .ios using [WinCDemu](https://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/) when i right click the drive to create image using WinCDemu, i get an error saying "access denied" (see attached screenshot 1 & 2).

Ive tried doing this as an admin user and i get the same error. Ive tried clicking into the drive and browising the file which i can do. Ive tried copying the files to a local folder on the computer and creating the .iso from the local folder but i get a different error (see screenshot below 3 & 4)

Essentially i just want an .iso image of W7 home / W7 pro. I understand Microsoft used to distribute these on their own site, but have stoped doing so as W7 is now end of life. The only reason i need it as one piece of specific software i have will only run on W7. Im not adverse to getting a W7 iso from somewhere else but just very cautious as to the source. Hence why ive tried to make my own from an official W7 install CD.

[image: prior to clicking on disk]

[image: error upon clicking on disk and creating iso]

[image: error on creating iso from local file]

[image: log error when creating iso from local file]

Comment: Try running the iso maker as administrator.

Comment: You can not directly convert an Windows installation into an installable or runnable ISO image. You first need to capture the installation into a WIM file and then replace from an existing Win 7 installer image the WIM file with your created one. If you don't have an Win 7 install DVD or ISO image just check ebay for a used disk.

Comment: Please, add to you post the output log for verifying by possible warnings and errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may download the Windows 7 ISO from many sources on the web
(except from Microsoft - or at least not without a third-party tool
to interface correctly to Microsoft).

The HowTo Geek article
[Where to Download Windows 10, 8.1, and 7 ISOs Legally](https://www.howtogeek.com/186775/how-to-download-windows-7-8-and-8.1-installation-media-legally/)
recommends using the
[Microsoft Windows and Office ISO Download Tool](https://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/67-microsoft-windows-iso-download-tool).

This tool downloads ISO for Windows and Office of all versions.
It does not require Administrator permissions. I found this tool
also recommended on several other websites.

The tool will suggest two Windows 7 versions, the original and also
"Windows 7 (August 2018)". The later is more up to date and can save
time.

Comment: The [Microsoft site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-7) doesn't offer Windows 7 iso anymore, so the download tool's unuseful at the moment for the OP.

Comment: @JorgeLuiz: Have you tried it before downvoting? I did try it, and it works.

Comment: Ok, so just add the **Microsoft link** to post for the OP can directly download the Win 7 ISO.

Comment: @JorgeLuiz: There is no Microsoft link publicly available, but all the ISOs are still there on the Microsoft site. This tool has the right links and initiates the download for you directly from Microsoft's servers.